# Changing the opacity of a class via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Heres the situation: 
I have two range sliders:

```
<input id="rangeOne" disabled class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="3">
```

and

```
<input id="rangeTwo" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="8">
```

If rangeTwo equals rangeOne, it's opacity must change to 0.5, but I have absolutely no idea how to make the JavaScript change values in CSS.

This is what I have so far as my JavaScript:

```
function changeAction() {
  if (rangeTwo.value == rangeOne.value) {
    document.getElementById("rangeTwo").style.opacity = 0.5;;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the range on input event for equality to set the *opacity* property:

```js
document.querySelector('#rangeTwo').addEventListener('input', function(){
  if(this.value < document.querySelector('#rangeOne').value)
    this.style.opacity = 0.5;
  else
    this.style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```html
<input id="rangeOne" disabled class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="3">
<input id="rangeTwo" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="8">
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it works, but the opacity changes as soon as the value is the same, can you make it so the opacity changes once I let go of the range slider?

Comment: @Joseph, simply use `<` instead of `==` in the condition....I have updated the answer....please check.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me:

```js
function changeAction() {
    if (rangeTwo.value == rangeOne.value) {
        document.getElementById("rangeTwo").style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="rangeOne" disabled class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="3" onchange="changeAction()">
<input id="rangeTwo" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="8" onchange="changeAction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly - also note the `;;` at the end of your statement. I've hooked the code up to a button, and also added an `else` so it changes the opacity back if the two are not equal:

```js
function changeAction() {
  if (rangeTwo.value == rangeOne.value) {
    document.getElementById("rangeTwo").style.opacity = 0.5;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("rangeTwo").style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="rangeOne" disabled class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="3">

<input id="rangeTwo" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="8">
<button onclick="changeAction()">Change Action</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that both yourself and the other posters have all advocated setting the style attribute on the element in response to external events. I'm of the opinion you should apply/remove a class that effects the same styling.

As such, I've gone about it thusly:

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onWindowLoaded, false);

function onWindowLoaded(evt)
{
 byId('rangeTwo').addEventListener('input', onRange2Change, false);
}

function onRange2Change(evt)
{
 if (this.value == byId('rangeOne').value)
  this.classList.add('seeThrough');
 else
  this.classList.remove('seeThrough');
}
```

```css
.seeThrough
{
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<input id="rangeOne" disabled class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="3">
 <input id="rangeTwo" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="8">
```